# Is Akka cluster a good choice for running multiple socket clients

Tags: websocket, akka, akka-cluster

I need to run 1000+ socket clients at several nodes. Each client listens to unique endpoint.

https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/client-side/websocket-support.html

I plan to represent each client as actor with supervision, recovery, event handling e.t.c. and hope that akka cluster will

- spawn my actors where each actor represents socket client
- supervision policies will help to recover actors from failing states
- evenly distribute actors across several nodes
- gives me guarantee that I have at most once actor for each client
- akka messaging will help me to enable communication between actors with at least once semantics.

What else should I expect?

Answer (score 1):

In general the Akka ecosystem has some reasonable patterns for what you're looking for:

- actor per client is a reasonable starting point; supervision helps a lot
- cluster sharding will evenly distribute actors across the cluster nodes and generally maintain at most one incarnation per sharding ID (you thus need to map each client to a distinct sharding ID).  In a split-brain scenario, there is the chance that you'd get the same client on both sides of a network partition: the split-brain resolver configuration governs the consistency vs. availability trade-off (basically it's up to you whether you'd rather have the failure mode be no active instance of a client or multiple active instances of a client).
- For ensuring that when a shard moves in a rebalancing, the clients in that shard are started on the new node, the two options are "remember entities" in cluster sharding and having a cluster singleton which regularly pings each client actor.  If the set to keep-alive is reasonably static, I tend to prefer the singleton approach.
- Akka's basic message semantics are at-most once, but there are well established and well documented patterns (most notably the ask pattern) for at-least-once.